# Why can't I pass this Json string into an Invoke-RestMethod in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, rest, automation

I'm trying to make a PUT request to an API. I am passing a Json string into the -Body of the request.

`$StudentId = 1234`

`$Body = { "name": "John Doe", "active": "no", "id": [$StudentId], "filters": [{"field":"major", "comparator":"==", "value":"cs"}, {"field":"minor", "comparator":"==", "value":"math"}]}`

I then input $Body into an Invoke-RestMethod:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Put -Body $Body -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{'Authorization' = '**********'; 'environment' = '*******'; 'token' = $Token}
```

When I run this in Powershell, I am getting many errors like these (can't paste exact code because its on a separate computer):

```
Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement, Missing argument in parameter list, ParseError (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
```

I am fairly new to Powershell and have not had any luck figuring out why it is having problems taking this Json as the -Body of the request. What am I doing wrong with this Json?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: @Theo hey, sorry for not responding sooner. Your answer did not work because the $UserId was a variable (I think this was the reason, but i am new enough to PS where I am not positive)...I managed to get it to work by figuring out the exact Powershell syntax to create a PS object and then convert it into JSON to attach as the -Body...I will post the correct code soon! Thanks for taking time to help me troubleshoot, though, because your answer did point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

The `$body` you declare is not a **string**.

The easiest is to declare it inside a Here-String:

```
$StudentId = 1234

$Body = @"
{ "name": "John Doe", "active": "no", "id": "$StudentId", "filters": [{"field":"major", "comparator":"==", "value":"cs"}, {"field":"minor", "comparator":"==", "value":"math"}]}
"@
```

and feed that to the `Invoke-RestMethod` call

<sup>P.S. if the StudentID is always numeric, you can leave out the quotes around it (`"id": $StudentId`)</sup>

---

If you have the input values as PSObjects, just use `ConvertTo-Json` like in the example below:

```
$StudentId = 1234

$Body = [PsCustomObject]@{ 
    "name"    = "John Doe"
    "active"  = "no"
    "id"      = "$StudentId"  # surround with quotes if this is meant to be a string
    "filters" = [PsCustomObject]@{"field" = "major"; "comparator" = "=="; "value" = "cs"},
                [PsCustomObject]@{"field" = "minor"; "comparator" = "=="; "value" = "math"}
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: I tried this and I am now getting this error: Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"status":400, "code":"bad_request","messages":["Unmarshal type error: expected=string, got=number, offset=100"] ---->InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException --->FullyQualifiedErrorId: WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: @miguelsantos10 Can't help you there as I have no idea what system you are trying to post the request to.. did you leave the quotes in around the student id?

Comment: I did not! I changed the quotes. Thanks for catching that!